# Adding 1 to the image name every time a new image is uploaded to folder

Tags: php, html, image, upload

I am a newbie at PHP and I'm learning.

I've made a basic script where you can upload an image to a director on the server. I want the image names to get a number at the end so that the name won't be duplicated.

This is my script to add 1 to the name (I'm really bad at "for loops"):

```
for(x=0; $imageName => 50000; x++){
$imageFolderName = $imageName.$x;
}
```

Please tell me if I'm doing this totally wrong.

Comment: The termination condition for your loop is slightly strange... Are you sure you don't want to be checking the value for `$x`?  `$x => 50000`?

Comment: I think it's easir to add timestamp to a pictures name than a value.. Timestamps are also pretty unique.. :)

Comment: The condition must be $x <= 50000 for sure, being 50000 the maximum of images you want to upload

Comment: The variable `x` also needs a dollar symbol prefix, in both cases in the `for` (aside from the fact that it probably needs using three times).

Comment: Gabriel, please edit your question to explain what the loop is meant to do, and people can then advise you.

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb, thanks all! I am so new to php.

Comment: Perhaps you may try `uniqid` method

Comment: I think I got it, thanks again, I really appreciate your answears!

Comment: if you only want to prevent having duplicated names, I would suggest to create the image name appending the current time stamp as integer. That way you will never have the same number and therefore a complete new file name.

Comment: You should use a database. Then you can store information about the images and use the database ID as your unique identifier.

Comment: I was just going to tell you guys that it's working now! Thanks to you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential trick to avoid looping:

```
$existingfiles = count(glob("files/*"));
// this assumes you are saving in a directory called files!
$finalName = $imageName.$existingfiles;
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again, because that helped me with another problem too!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Niet's answer, you can do a foreach loop on all the files in your folder and prepend a number to the file name like so:

```
<?
    $directory = 'directory_name';
    $files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('.', '..'));
    $count = 0;

    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $count++;
        rename($file, $count.'-'.$file);
    }
?>
```

Alternatively you could rename the file to the timestamp of when it was uploaded and prepend some random characters to the file with the rand() function:

```
<?
    $uploaded_name = 'generic-image.jpeg';
    $new_name = time().rand(0, 999).$uploaded_name;
?>
```

You'll need to handle and move the uploaded files before and after the rename, but you get the general gist of how this would work.

Comment: Thank you! I will be testing that :)